# linear space - considerations about dimensions

Tags: linear-algebra

> $X$ is linear space and $U$, $V$ are subspaces of $X$ and $\dim U= 4$, $\dim V=6$, $\dim X = 10$. Then:
>   **a.** $X = U \oplus V$,
>   **b.** $\dim(U \cap V)\geq 2$,
>   **c.** $\dim(U+V) = \dim(X) \implies U \cap V = \{0\}$.

**a.**
It is not true.
Take $X = \operatorname{span}(e_1, \dotsc, e_{10})$, $U = \operatorname{span}(e_1, \dotsc, e_4)$ and $V = \operatorname{span}(e_1, \dotsc, e_6)$. 
Then $(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1) \in X$, but $(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1)\notin U \oplus V$.

**b.**
I don't know how to solve it. Can you help me?

**c.**
Is not true:
If $X = U = V = \operatorname{span}(e_1, \dotsc, e_{10})$, then $U + V = X$.

What about correctness of **a** and **c**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your counterexample for **c** doesn’t work, because in this case $\dim U = \dim V = 10$, but it is given that $\dim U = 4$ and $\dim V = 6$.

Your counterexample for **a** works, but instead of $U \oplus V$ you need to write $U + V$, because the sum is not direct.

Hint for **c**:
This are straightforward application of a dimension formula, which relates $\dim(U + V)$ and $\dim(U \cap V)$.

Hint for **b**:
Try to construct a counterexample, similarly to **a**.
You can also use the dimension formula mentioned above to translate the inequality $\dim(U \cap V) \geq 2$ into an equivalent inequality concerning $\dim(U+V)$, which may be more intuitive to you.

Comment: Thanks to relation **c** is true, yeah ? Tomorrow I will consider **b**.

Comment: Yes, statement **c** is true.

Comment: For **b**. $U=span(e_1,...,e_4)$, $V=(e_5,...,e_{10})$  $U+V=X$. $\dim U\cap V) = 0$. Ok ?

Comment: Yes, this works (it is also the counterexample I tought about).